# SQL update one single row table with data from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. The first one with all movements in twelve months and the second one with claims registered in the same period of time. When I run the following query from the first table I've got 10 records. Of course, there are other records with a different number of movements (e.g.: 7, 23, 2 movements):

```
select t.cod_suc
      ,t.cod_ramo_comercial
      ,t.Poliza
      ,t.Item
      ,t.id_pv
from temp_portafolio_personal_accidents as t
where t.cod_suc = 2
      and t.cod_ramo_comercial = 46
      and t.Poliza = 50283
      and t.Item = 1
      and t.id_pv = 788383;
```

[image]

With the second query, for the second table, I have the following results:

```
select c.cod_suc
      ,c.cod_ramo_comercial
      ,c.[No. Policy]
      ,c.Item
      ,c.[ID Incident]
      ,max(c.id_pv) as id_pv
      ,count(distinct [No. Incident]) as 'Conteo R12'
from #claims as c
where c.[ID Incident] = 343632
group by c.cod_suc
        ,c.cod_ramo_comercial
        ,c.[No. Policy]
        ,c.Item
        ,c.[ID Incident];
```

[image]

Now, I need to update the first table but only one record. I'm using the following query, but all records are being updated. When I sum results I have 10 but is just one claim, as the second query shows.

```
update p
set [No. Siniestros R12] = b.[Conteo R12]
from temp_portafolio_personal_accidents p
    left join
     (select c.cod_suc
            ,c.cod_ramo_comercial
            ,c.[No. Policy]
            ,c.Item
            ,c.[ID Incident]
            ,max(c.id_pv) as id_pv
            ,count(distinct [No. Incident]) as 'Conteo R12'
      from
           #claims as c
      where c.[ID Incident] = 343632
      group by c.cod_suc
              ,c.cod_ramo_comercial
              ,c.[No. Policy]
              ,c.Item
              ,c.[ID Incident]
     ) b
        on p.id_pv = b.id_pv
           and p.cod_suc = b.cod_suc
           and p.cod_ramo_comercial = b.cod_ramo_comercial
           and p.Poliza = b.[No. Policy]
           and p.Item = b.Item
where p.id_pv = 788383;
```

Comment: Your table temp_portafolio_personal_accidents   have an id  ( a unique row  identifier  ) ?

Comment: Can you specify which "one record" you want to update? Any of them would do?

Comment: And why do you use the "left join"? If there is no corresponding record, then will you set the [No. ... R12] to NULL?

Comment: No matter the record to be updated. And I don't have a unique ID in table temp_portafolio_personal_accidents, but I'm free to add a new column maybe with a row_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE with a `ROW_NUMBER()` function to do this.  Simple example:

```
DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE (Testing INT, Testing2 VARCHAR(55), Testing3 BIT);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '1', 1);

WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Testing) AS RowID
        ,Testing
        ,Testing2
        ,Testing3
    FROM @TABLE
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Testing = 2, Testing2 = '2', Testing3 = 0
WHERE RowID = 1
;
SELECT * FROM @TABLE
;
```